# Script Product Import PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: php, script, prestashop, prestashop1.7

Estoy iniciándome en PrestaShop (versión 1.7) y he creado un pequeño Script para automatizar la importación de productos, pero parece que no me funciona.

Dejo el código y explico las dudas que me surgen a ver si alguien me los podría aclarar.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


define("BASE_PROJECTE",realpath(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../'));

include_once(BASE_PROJECTE . '/../config/settings.inc.php');
include_once(BASE_PROJECTE . '/../config/config.inc.php');
//include_once(BASE_PROJECTE . '/../controllers/admin/AdminImportController.php');
include(BASE_PROJECTE .'/../init.php');

$context = Context::getContext();

$import = New AdminImportControllerCore();
loadProductsPost();
$import->productImport();


function loadProductsPost() {

    $_POST = array (
        'tab' => 'AdminImport',
        'forceIDs' => '1',
        'skip' => '1',
        'csv' => 'productos.csv',
        'entity' => '1',
        'separator' => ';',
        'multiple_value_separator' => ',',
        'iso_lang' => 'es',
        'convert' => '',
        'import' => '1',
        "type_value" => array(
            0 => 'id',
            1 => 'active',
            2 => 'name',
            3 => 'category',
            4 => 'price_tex',
            5 => 'id_tax_rules_group',
            6 => 'wholesale_price',
            7 => 'on_sale',
            8 => 'reduction_price',
            9 => 'reduction_percent',
            10 => 'reduction_from',
            11 => 'reduction_to',
            12 => 'reference',
            13 => 'supplier_reference',
            14 => 'supplier',
            15 => 'manufacturer',
            16 => 'ean13',
            17 => 'upc',
            18 => 'ecotax',
            29 => 'width',
            20 => 'height',
            21 => 'depth',
            22 => 'weight',
            23 => 'quantity',
            24 => 'minimal_quantity',
            25 => 'visibility',
            26 => 'additional_shipping_cost',
            27 => 'unity',
            28 => 'unit_price',
            29 => 'description_short',
            30 => 'description',
            31 => 'tags',
            32 => 'meta_title',
            33 => 'meta_keywords',
            34 => 'meta_description',
            36 => 'text_when_in_stock',
            37 => 'text_when_backorder_allowed',
            41 => 'show_price',
            42 => 'image',
            43 => 'image_alt',
            44 => 'delete_existing_images',
            45 => 'features',
            46 => 'online_only',
            47 => 'condition',
            48 => 'customizable',
            49 => 'uploadable_files',
            50 => 'text_fields',
            51 => 'out_of_stock',
            52 => 'is_virtual',
            53 => 'file_url',
            54 => 'nb_downloadable',
            55 => 'date_expiration',
            56 => 'nb_days_accessible',
            57 => 'shop',
            58 => 'advanced_stock_management',
            59 => 'depends_on_stock',
            60 => 'warehouse',
            61 => 'accessories',

        ),
    );
}

Tools::clearSmartyCache();
Tools::clearXMLCache();
Media::clearCache();
Tools::generateIndex();


?>
```

He creado una carpeta Script en la raíz del proyecto, junto a todas las carpetas principales. Dentro he creado el archivo .php con el Script anterior y en la misma carpeta he guardado el productos.csv.

Entro en la url del Script para ejecutarlo, se queda la pantalla en blanco, pero no me crea los productos.

-Tengo que ubicar el script en otro sitio o para ejecutarlo debo de hacerlo de otra manera en vez de acceder a la url?

-Me falta hacer algún include para que funcione?

-Puede ser debido a que el formato del .csv no es idéntico al formato del array del script?

Gracias!

Comment: En le hilo de esta pagina explico como crear un script:
[\[Solucionado\] Script Importacion Prestashop 1.7](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/893890-solucionado-script-importacion-prestashop-17/?tab=comments#comment-3287996)
Leer los diferentes comentarios y soluciones.
Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me respondo y me corrijo a mi mismo por si a alguien le sirve mas adelante.

- Primero de todo, el script .php para hacer la importación lo he ubicado en la carpeta adminxxxx de mi prestashop y el archivo .csv con los productos, dentro de la carpeta   adminxxxx/import.
- El formato del array del script debe relacionarse con los campos del .csv de manera exacta, si algún campo no se tiene o no se usa, lo marcaremos con un "no".
- Me faltaba crear un empleado para poder crear los productos, ya que me daba un error de que no estaba logueado. Para hacer esto, añadimos el siguiente código después de los includes y los use:

  $context = Context::getContext();

  $employee = new Employee(1);

  $context->employee = $employee;

A continuación adjunto el script entero. (Tener también en cuenta que para subir las imágenes se deberán tocar mas cosas.)

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd());

//include_once(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_ . '/../config/settings.inc.php');
include_once(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_ . '/../config/config.inc.php');


use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Import\Configuration\ImportConfigInterface;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Tools;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\ConfigurationInterface;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Hook\HookDispatcherInterface;
use Tools as LegacyTools;

$context = Context::getContext();
$employee = new Employee(1);
$context->employee = $employee;


function loadProductsPost() {

    $_POST = array (
        'tab' => 'AdminImport',
        'forceIDs' => '0',
        'skip' => '1',
        'csv' => 'productos.csv',
        'entity' => '1',
        'separator' => ';',
        'multiple_value_separator' => ',',
        'iso_lang' => 'es',
        'convert' => '',
        'import' => 'Importar datos csv',
        'type_value' => array(
            0 => 'id',
            1 => 'active',
            2 => 'no', //revisar
            3 => 'category',
            4 => 'price_tex',
            5 => 'id_tax_rules_group',
            6 => 'on_sale',
            7 => 'reduction_price',
            8 => 'reduction_percent',
            9 => 'reduction_from',
            10 => 'reduction_to',
            11 => 'reference',
            12 => 'supplier_reference',
            13 => 'supplier',
            14 => 'ean13',
            15 => 'height',
            16 => 'width',
            17 => 'depth',
            18 => 'weight',
            19 => 'quantity',
            20 => 'no',
            21 => 'minimal_quantity',
            22 => 'no',
            23 => 'no',
            24 => 'description',
            25 => 'no',
            26 => 'no',
            27 => 'no',
            28 => 'meta_title',
            29 => 'no',
            30 => 'no',
            31 => 'no',
            32 => 'image',
            33 => 'customizable',
            34 => 'visibility',
            35 => 'delivery_time',
            36 => 'features',
            37 => 'no',
            38 => 'no',
            39 => 'no',
            40 => 'no',
            41 => 'manufacturer',


        ),
    );
}


$import = New AdminImportControllerCore();
loadProductsPost();
$import->productImport();


echo ('ejecutado');
?>
```